# ImportError: cannot import name AUTH

Tags: cloud

I have installed euca2ools.3.0.1 from source in a custom location
OS : RHEL 5.7

I have sourced "eucarc" for importing the settings of ecualytus cloud.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "euca2ools_3_0_2/bin/euca-register", line 5, in <module>
pkg_resources.run_script('euca2ools==3.0.1', 'euca-register')
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 528, in run_script
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1394, in run_script
File "euca2ools_3_0_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/euca2ools-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO    /scripts/euca-register", line 3, in <module>
import euca2ools.commands.euca.registerimage
File "euca2ools_3_0_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/euca2ools-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/euca2ools    /commands/euca/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
from requestbuilder import Arg, MutuallyExclusiveArgList, AUTH, SERVICE
ImportError: cannot import name AUTH
```

Can i know why I am not able to run ?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you figured it out [here](https://groups.google.com/a/eucalyptus.com/forum/#!searchin/euca-users/cannot$20import$20name$20AUTH/euca-users/DKwiUsnABJM/nEaa7xl4pxkJ). Have to downgrade to requestbuilder 0.1.0.

```
sudo pip uninstall requestbuilder
sudo pip install requestbuilder==0.1.0
```